# CyclicBarrier not working as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, cyclicbarrier

I am trying to simulate a triatlon competition using `CyclicBarrier` but it doesn't work as expected and I don't know why.

Each part of the competition has to wait till all the runners have completed the previous one, but it seems like it's waiting forever.

This is the piece of code for the phase one:

```
class Runner implements Runnable
{
    private CyclicBarrier bar = null;
    private static int runners;
    private static double[] time;
    private int number;
    public static String name;

    public Runner(int runners, String name)
    {
        time = new double[runners];
        for (int i=0; i<runners; i++)
            time[i] = 0;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Runner(CyclicBarrier bar, int number)
    {   
        this.bar = bar;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try { int i = bar.await(); } 
                   catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
                       catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {}
        double tIni = System.nanoTime();
        try { Thread.sleep((int)(100*Math.random()); } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        double t = System.nanoTime() - tIni;
        time[number] += t;
    }
}

public class Triatlon
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int runners = 100;
    CyclicBarrier Finish_Line_1 = new CyclicBarrier (runners);

    Runner c = new Runner(runners, "Triatlon");

    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(runners);

    for (int i=0; i<runners; i++)
        e.submit(new Runner(Finish_Line_1, i));

    System.out.println(Finish_Line_1.getNumberWaiting()); // this always shows 99
    try { int i = Finish_Line_1.await(); } 
           catch(InterruptedException e01) {} 
             catch (BrokenBarrierException e02) {}
    System.out.println("Swimming phase completed");

        // here the rest of the competition, which works the same way
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CyclicBarrier` cycles around once all parties have called await and the barrier is opened. Hence the name.
So if you create it with 5 parties and there are 6 calls to `await` the last one will trigger it to be waiting again for 4 more parties to join.

That's basically what happens here as you have the 1 extra `await` call in your main.   It is waiting for another runners-1 calls to happen.

The simple fix is to create the `CyclicBarrier` with runners+1 parties.

Answer (score 5):

You have an off-by-one error: you create a `CyclicBarrier` for 100 threads, but execute 101 `await`s, the one-off being in the main method. Due to the semantics of the cyclic barrier, and subject to nondeterministic conditions, your main thread will be the last to execute `await`, thereby being left alone waiting for another 99 threads to join in.

After you fix this problem, you'll find out that the application keeps running even after all work is done. This is because you didn't call `e.shutdown()`, so all the threads in the pool stay alive after the main thread is done.

BTW `getNumberWaiting` always shows 0 for me, which is the expected value after the barrier has been lowered due to 100 submitted threads reaching it. This is nondeterministic, however, and could change at any time.

Comment: You've got the point. I would add that I think that it should be `Thread.sleep(...)` then `barrier.await()` in each run method. In fact runners run, then wait for others to join

Comment: @Grooveek That would make more sense, yes---and would mask OP's error because then one of the threads from the pool would be stuck. Depending on the rest of the code, the error may bubble up in the next stint, with an even murkier origin.

Comment: Thanks! That gives a solution to my problem. I see an anomaly though. After printing "Swimming phase completed" the program doesn't finish, as if it was waiting for anything else to happen.

Comment: Also your comments here make the program work, but I don't understand two things: 1) why would it make more sense, because placing the barrier before having the runner run (`Thread.sleep(...)`) means that all the runners are ready to go, so they all start the race together when the barrier is lifted; 2) why doing it this way masks the error?

Comment: 1) Now that you explain it, it makes sense the way it is. 2) If you first slept, then `await`ed, then the main thread would get to `await` before one of the runners. Therefore the last of the runners to call `await` would be left waiting forever, but the main thread would proceed. Then, at the next stint, there wouldn't be enough threads to run all your submitted tasks, so one of the tasks would wait in the queue indefinitely, blocking all others which `await` it.

Comment: Why your program doesn't finish: you didn't call `e.shutdown()` and the application keeps going after the main thread is done.

Comment: Back to point 1) again, I had to do it your way else the times it took the runners to finish phase 1 weren't registered. According to the not finishing program issue, right, I forgot to do that... But I just added `e.shutdown()` to my program and the same thing keeps happening. Also, I just detected a really weird issue: for phase 2 the time it takes for runner 99 to complete is ALWAYS 0, and also for runner 98 in phase 3, ALWAYS. I'm doing this: `Thread.sleep((long)(100+2000*Math.random()));`, it is random and it can't be 0, why is this happening?

Comment: I guess the issue with runners 98 and 99 in phases 2 and 3 is happening precisely because of that "stuck thread" you're talking about... Honestly I don't know how to put a solution to it.